# What "maturity level" do we want for the blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

We've been asked what level of explicit content we want to allow on the blog -- PG, PG-13, higher?  In discussing biology and especially xenobiology, it can sometimes be necessary to discuss the physiology of mating.  Also, some sociology/culture-focused posts might need to address sexual practices.

Is any (worldbuilding-relevant) topic ok so long as it's discussed "clinically"?  Are there topics we do not want to see covered at all?  What about fiction?

What guidance should we give to authors?

Comment: Relevant posts about the same issues applied to the site: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2412/627, http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2697/627.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Considering that most posts on here are intellectual - that is, the people who write them are intelligent, and probably mature - I'm sure vulgarity won't offend the majority of people.

That being said, the group of people on here will want a reasonable amount of maturity - no excessive or unreasonable use of vulgar or crude language.

For the sake of community use, PG-13 is probably high enough to satisfy enough people's wants - as long as language involved is used in a mature context, and is not being used to offend a person or group

Comment: PG-13 is a good level; children under 13 are required to be under parental supervision to use the site, so most of the audience will either be 13+ or have "parental guidance".

Comment: 13+ is required to register on the site, not necessarily view, AFAIK.

Comment: +1 I think that this, plus noticing the 'intent' of the question, are good direction.

Answer (score 5):

Vulgarity is unnecessary except where it's actually the topic in question, it being an important part of any language, and language being one of our regular topics.

Beyond that we are (probably) mostly adults and able to take these things as they come but it shouldn't be used without reason. I could see it being more of a thing with character building but that's not really within our remit.

In the same light I'm sure we're perfectly capable of having a discussion about reproductive behaviors, whether recreational or procreative, in an entirely academic manner.

In terms of the actual use of the words in question, I no reason to obfuscate or censor, though judicious editing or a request to tone it down is reasonable if someone is pushing their luck. In practice very few people actually swear in writing, it's mostly a spoken thing.

Comment: I wish. A question about secondary sexual characteristics fell over because the answers weren't discussed "in an entirely academic manner" although they should or could have been, which is a pity. The topic was in a cognitive blindspot, once closed there was no point reopening it. Less painful for the OP. Yet it was ideal for WB. Vulgarity as a linguistic topic, definitely.